# Font rendering issue on one browser and one PC

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have a goofy font problem that only happens on my primary Windows 7 machine and my primary browser Chrome.  The problem seems to be with font-awesome but I may be wrong about that. In the screenshots below, the first is messed up and the 2nd appears normal. I've updated chrome, compared versions, looked at other windows 7 desktops. Every other system seems fine.  Is there a font cache somewhere that I can purge and hopefully reload properly?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just a wild guess, is [DirectWrite](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/chrome-font-rendering-windows/) turned off on the faulty machine. You can find the setting on chrome://flags

Comment: It's certainly NOT font-awesome since there are no icons.